# I need a ObservableCollection of tree levels

Tags: c#-4.0

i need to create a ObservableCollection<> for tree o more levels in c# like this:

- Group 1
- Group 2

  - Group 1
  - Group 2

    - Group 1
    - Group 2
  - Group 3

thanks in advance,

Timmy Leonard

Answer (score 0):

make a "node" class that contains an observable collection of child nodes, like this:

```
class node
{
// add some data properties in here, too

   public ObservableCollection<node> children;
}


// declare an instance, in the data model (or where-ever)
ObservableCollection<node> RootLevel = new ObservableCollection<node>();
```

I could probably give you a better answer if I knew what platform your trying to do this for. (WPF or Silverlight, etc)

Comment: I got the idea i will try it,the platform i am using is WPF,